# Actively logging assignments in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to set up a way in R to print details of an each assignment while R code is run. So, for example, if the code `x <- 1` is run then `x has been assigned 1` will automatically be printed.

Is this possible?
I have two thoughts on how this might be done but can't figure out if either is possible.

1. redefine the `=` primitive so that it also prints a message
2. have an assignment trigger another function to run

Comment: Does it literally have to log it like that? Or is
 `> print(+  x <- 1+ )` sufficient? You can wrap `print` over the assignment itself.

Comment: I strongly recommend *against* redefining `=` for the purpose of logging. Even if it were safe to override a primitive in this fashion, realize that every single function in R uses it: for every single logging line you want to see, you're likely to see hundreds of inner (base R) uses that would crush the purpose (signal-vs-noise).

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that could be implemented at a higher level so that every line of code with an assignment did not have to be edited. Ideally, a piece of code could be placed at the top of an older code file and that would be enough to create all of the needed prints.

Comment: @r2evans this is a very good point. Hopefully I can figure out a different work around

Comment: J Chan ... I don't know why you need that level of observation, but you might consider creating a custom getter/setter class and keep the variables you need tracked in there. It will give you custom control over what to do when a value is "set". It'll have not-insignificant overhead, but it'll log only what you want it to.

Comment: Are you familiar with the premise of a getter/setter "class"? It doesn't have to be fancy.

Comment: `"%assign%" <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  v <- rlang::quo_name(rlang::enquo(lhs))
  assign(v, rhs,
         envir = .GlobalEnv)
  print(sprintf("%s has been assigned %s", v, rhs))
}`

Comment: @r2evans do you think something like the above would be appropriate? It has the disadvantage of assigning only in the global environment, but do you foresee other issues that would make this a bad way to implement?

Comment: If that were the way to go, I wouldn't hard-code `.GlobalEnv`, there's no need, let it default to the current environment and it would work the same in functions. That's not necessarily what I was thinking, but it's certainly an option.

Comment: @r2evans This is a nice solution but I'm trying to implement something that won't require going back to edit older code.

Comment: JChan, I think you're stuck. Either accept the risk of overwriting a `.Primitive` function, and the 100s if not 1000s of noise in your signal, or go back and modify code. (Or neither, and perhaps we can "X/Y-problem" the issue you think justifies this approach.)

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution, but requires editing the code would be

```r
# custom assignment function  -----------------------------------------------------------------

`%<-%` <- function (lhs, rhs)  {
  cl <- match.call()
  lhs <- substitute(lhs)
  env <- parent.frame()
  message("Info: `", lhs, "` defined as `", enquote(cl$rhs)[2], "`")

  invisible(eval(assign(x = paste(lhs),
              value = rhs,
              envir = env))
  )
}

# some tests ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ad  %<-% c(1,2,33)
#> Info: `ad` defined as `c(1, 2, 33)`
ac %<-% 22
#> Info: `ac` defined as `22`
ad %<-% 22
#> Info: `ad` defined as `22`

df <- mtcars
df %<-%  mtcars
#> Info: `df` defined as `mtcars`
```

If you don't want to modify files, you can define a modified `source()` function to replace the assignments with the newly defined `%<-%` function.

```r
source_loudly <- function(filePath, ...) {
  file_con <- file(filePath, open = "r")
  txt <- readLines(file_con)
  close(file_con)

  txt_mod <- gsub(pattern = "<-", replace = "%<-%", x = txt)
  source(textConnection(txt_mod), ...)
}

filePath <- "R/bits/example.R" # point to a local file on your pc
source_loudly(filePath = filePath, echo = T)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a getter/setter hack that comes close without costing too much. While it does require you to change existing code, it has the benefit that you can change the initial assignment to `list` instead of `tracer` and everything continues to work unchanged.

```r
tracer <- local({
  .e <- NULL
  function(..., name = "unk") {
    .e <<- list(...)
    .e$.name <<- name
    `class<-`(.e, c("tracer", "environment"))
  }
})

`[.tracer` <- `[[.tracer` <- `$.tracer` <- function(x, i) {
  cat(sprintf("get: %s\n", deparse(substitute(i))))
  NextMethod()
}

`[<-.tracer` <- `[[<-.tracer` <- `$<-.tracer` <- function(x, i, value) {
  cat(sprintf("set: %s <- %s\n", deparse(substitute(i)),
              substr(paste(deparse(substitute(value)), collapse = " "), 1, 80)))
  NextMethod()
}
```

Notes:

- `deparse` tends to split long lines into a vector of strings; this is mitigated here with `paste(..., collapse=" ")`;
- ... but long literal values (e.g., frames) can be a bit annoying in the logs, so I arbitrarily chose `substr(., 1, 80)` as a reasonable size to log.
- this hints at one problem I'll expand on below: this doesn't tell you *which* columns have been modified, just that the object has been updated.

Demonstration with "simple" objects:

```r
quux <- tracer(a=1, b=2:3, d=list(pi, "a"), mt=mtcars[1:2,])
quux$a
# get: "a"
# [1] 1
quux$a <- 11
# set: "a" <- 11
quux$b
# get: "b"
# [1] 2 3
quux$b <- 2:5
# set: "b" <- 2:5
quux$b
# get: "b"
# [1] 2 3 4 5
```

So far, so good. Now onto the list:

```r
quux$d
# get: "d"
# [[1]]
# [1] 3.141593
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
quux$d[[1]]
# get: "d"
# [1] 3.141593
quux$d[[1]] <- pi^2
# get: "d"
# set: "d" <- list(9.86960440108936, "a")
```

The latter needs some explanation, notably about the order of operations. The assignment is really `` `[[<-`(quux$d, 1, pi^2) ``, which is not traced. This adjusts the first element of the list, and then assigns this new list back to `quux$d`, where our `$<-.tracer` sees that full-list reassignment.

That is not completely unreasonable for small objects, but it becomes a little more annoying with larger objects:

```r
quux$mt$cyl
# get: "mt"
# [1] 6 6
quux$mt$cyl <- quux$mt$cyl + 5
# get: "mt"
# get: "mt"
# set: "mt" <- structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21), cyl = c(11, 11), disp = c(160,  160), hp = c(110, 110), drat = c(3.9, 3.9), wt = c(2.62, 2.875 ), qsec = c(16.46, 17.02), vs = c(0, 0), am = c(1, 1), gear = c(4,  4), c
quux$mt$cyl
# get: "mt"
# [1] 11 11
```

Similarly, for an assignment we see both the first "get" step and then the whole-object-reassignment. (It is cutoff because I used `substr(., 1, 80)`.)

Also, note that in both `quux$d` and `quux$mt`, the tracer functions never see the sub-element or column being adjusted. Since R orders the operations as it does, our tracer functions cannot reveal what is going on there (easily).

---

Now, when you're ready to remove this level of activity-logging, just replace your initial call to `tracer(.)` with `list(.)`, and all operations continue to work but without logging.

```r
quux <- list(a=1, b=2:3, d=list(pi, "a"), mt=mtcars[1:2,])
quux$a
# [1] 1
quux$a <- 11
quux$b
# [1] 2 3
quux$b <- 2:5
quux$b
# [1] 2 3 4 5

quux$d
# [[1]]
# [1] 3.141593
# [[2]]
# [1] "a"
quux$d[[1]]
# [1] 3.141593
quux$d[[1]] <- pi^2

quux$mt$cyl
# [1] 6 6
quux$mt$cyl <- quux$mt$cyl + 5
quux$mt$cyl
# [1] 11 11
```